# How to find the lowest value from maximum values via has_many relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
Product.all.map { |p| p.reviews.maximum(:created_at) }.min
```

I would like to find the lowest values from maximum values.

Is it doable in one database query without using `map` and `min` methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it could be achieved in one query. You could `select` from `Review` and `group_by` `product_id`, then calculate `max` `created_at` in each group, for example:

```rb
Review
  .select("MAX(created_at) OVER (PARTITION BY product_id) AS max_created_at")
  .order(max_created_at: :asc)
  .first
  .max_created_at
```